# JavaScript reduce behavior with/without an initial value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sum the squares of numbers of an array by JavaScript `reduce` function. But the result differs when `reduce` method is called with or without the initial value.

```
var x = [75, 70, 73, 78, 80, 69, 71, 72, 74, 77];
console.log(x.slice().reduce((ac,n) => ac+(n*n))); // 49179
console.log(x.slice().reduce((ac,n) => ac+(n*n),0)); // 54729
```

This should be equivalent to the calls above:

```
console.log(x.slice().map(val => val*val).reduce((ac,n) => ac+n)); // 54729
```

In this case however both method returns the same value.

```
console.log([1,2,3].slice().reduce((ac,z) => ac+(z*z))); // 14
console.log([1,2,3].slice().reduce((ac,z) => ac+(z*z), 0)); // 14
```

**Why are the results of the first two calls different and the last two the same?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you don't provide the second parameter to `.reduce()`, it uses the first element of the array as the accumulator and starts at the second element.

In the first example, your first result of the `.reduce()` iteration is

```
75 + 70 * 70
```

while in the second version where pass in an explicit `0` it's

```
0 + 75 * 75
```

The cascade of computations from that leads to different results.

In the second example, you'll end up computing

```
1 + 2 * 2
```

and then

```
5 + 3 * 3
```

in the first line, which gives 14. In the second version, when you start with `0`, you'll compute

```
0 + 1 * 1
1 + 2 * 2
5 + 3 * 3
```

which is also 14.

Comment: I see. So it would skip the call to (n*n). That makes sense.