# Can someone explain to me in the simplest of terms how the reduce method works exactly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I am doing an exercise from The Odin Project where I need to find the oldest person within an array of objects (consisting of people of different ages) by using the array.reduce method. I got it working by looking up the solution trying to code along. I spent days trying to wrap my head around how the reduce method works the way it does in this scenario, but I don't get it.

From what I gather, a function is generally passed to the reduce method with two parameter that always represent 1) the accumulated value of the array and 2) the current element being iterated over. But in the code that I'm posting below, the parameters seem to work in a way where they're used to compare different objects within the array.

My question is this: The parameter 'oldest' clearly represents the oldest person in the array. That is *one* person. *One* element. How does that work, when the that parameter is supposed to represent the *accumulated* value of the array and, thus, several elements added together?

What am I not getting?

```
  const findTheOldest = function(array) { 
// Use reduce method to reduce the array by comparing current age with previous age
  return array.reduce((oldest, currentPerson) => {
    // oldestAge gets the age of the oldest person's year of death and birth
    const oldestAge = getAge(oldest.yearOfBirth, oldest.yearOfDeath);

    // currentAge gets the age of the current person's year of death and birth
    const currentAge = getAge(currentPerson.yearOfBirth, currentPerson.yearOfDeath);

    // return name if current age is older than the oldest age, else return current oldest age
    return oldestAge < currentAge ? currentPerson : oldest;
  });

};

const getAge = function(birth, death) {
 if (!death) {
death = new Date().getFullYear(); // return current year using Date()
}
return death - birth; // else just return age using death minus birth

console.log(findTheOldest(people).name); // Ray
```

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: The accumulator parameter doesn't *have* to be an accumulation of anything. It can be whatever you want it to be. The sum of values, the highest value, the lowest value, an object such as `{red:2, blue:3, white:0}`, or whatever makes sense in the particular use case.

Comment: jarmod - aha, that brings me closer to understanding why the code works. my question would be, then, which part of the code in question, exactly, decides what purpose the accumulator parameter serves?

Comment: The reducer function is called multiple times (once per person in the array). It compares the age of the person stored in `oldest` (the accumulator) with the age of the person stored in `currentPerson` and returns whichever is older. That *older* person is then the accumulator value for the next invocation of the reducer function, to which the next person in the array is passed. At any given time the accumulator represents the oldest person found so far (and is undefined for the first invocation of the reduce function) because you didn't send an initial value to reduce.

Comment: Correction to earlier comment - the [initial accumulator value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50826718/javascript-reduce-behavior-with-without-an-initial-value) is the first person in the array (it's not undefined) and reduce is called N-1 times. Watch all examples [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqnSE2hLwBI) but particularly the min/max salary example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accumulator parameter doesn't have to be an accumulation of anything. It can be whatever you want it to be. The sum of values, the highest value, the lowest value, a frequency counting object such as `{red:2, blue:3, white:0}`, or whatever makes sense in a particular use case.

The [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function works as follows:

> reduce executes a user-supplied "reducer" callback function on each element of the array, in order, passing in the return value from the calculation on the preceding element. The final result of running the reducer across all elements of the array is a single value.

Note that if you don't provide an initial accumulator value then JavaScript simply uses the array element at index 0 as the initial accumulator value and the array iteration starts at the 2nd element in the array.

Here are some examples of how to use reduce to solve various problems. The first is your typical, classic reduce scenario to sum a property (salary). The 2nd and 3rd are common min/max examples. The final one is a bit more sophisticated and it groups values by some property (an employee's team).

```js
const employees = [
  { name: "joe", age: 23, salary: 12000, team: "sales" },
  { name: "mary", age: 41, salary: 15000, team: "hr" },
  { name: "bob", age: 37, salary: 13000, team: "eng" },
  { name: "alice", age: 21, salary: 11000, team: "eng" },
];

// What is the total payroll (initial accumulated value 0)?
const payroll = employees.reduce((total, current) => {
  return total + current.salary;
}, 0);

// Which is the youngest employee (no initial value)?
const youngest_employee = employees.reduce((youngest, current) => {
  return youngest.age < current.age ? youngest : current;
});

// Which is the highest paid employee (no initial value)?
const highest_paid_employee = employees.reduce((highest, current) => {
  return highest.salary > current.salary ? highest : current;
});

// Which employees work for each team (initial value is object with
// key/value pairs of team names to empty array of employee names)?
const team_employee_names = employees.reduce(
  (accumulator, current) => {
    accumulator[current.team].push(current.name);
    return accumulator;
  },
  { sales: [], hr: [], eng: [] }
);

console.log("Payroll:", payroll);
console.log("Youngest:", youngest_employee.name);
console.log("Highest paid:", highest_paid_employee.name);
console.log("Employee names by team:", team_employee_names);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first value is the value returned from the previous iteration.

When you are using `reduce` as an accumulator, then the value you return is the accumulated value and it is common to give it a name indicating that.

For example:

```
[1,2,3].reduce( 
    (accumulator, current) =>  accumulator + current,
    0
);
```

In the case of the code in your question, the returned value is the older of the previous value and the current value so a different name is used.