# Mapping flattened data structure to a nested json structure in js

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting a dataset back from my database in a flattened structure like this:

```
   [
       {manufacture:Ford, make:Mustang, model:EcoBoost}, 
       {manufacture:Ford, make:Mustang, model:GTFastback},
       {manufacture:Ford, make:Mustang, model:DarkHorse},
       {manufacture:Ford, make:Escape, model:Active},
       {manufacture:Ford, make:Escape, model:Platium},
       {manufacture:Toyota, make:Camry, model:XSE},
       {manufacture:Toyota, make:Camry, model:TRD},
       {manufacture:Toyota, make:Camry, model:XLE},
       {manufacture:Toyota, make:Supra, model:2.0},
       {manufacture:Toyota, make:Supra, model:3.0}
   ]
```

I have a json structure defined as:
{manufacture:string,makes: [{make:string, models: [{model:string}]}}

I'm looking for a simple way to put that flattened data into  the json structure.

I can iterate through each record and manual add then into the strucutre, but there must be a simplier way to do this in js.

Comment: As for a potentially simpler way to do this in JavaScript, use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a custom reducer function. Arguable whether or not it is simpler, but it's the functional way to do this. Basic examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77312396/can-someone-explain-to-me-in-the-simplest-of-terms-how-the-reduce-method-works-e/77312687#77312687).

Comment: Not really my data structure, just used it to illustrate what I was trying to do to keep things simple.  Thank you for the reduce suggestion, I will give it a try.

Comment: This is just a nested group-by. I know there is a dupe for it but it will take a while to find it. The below flagged dupe is the basic, but you'll need to nest it for `make`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group array items using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688459/group-array-items-using-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the `manufacture` column and `manufacture + make` you see a lot of duplication. We can use an object to cache existing entries. We can even throw all levels of this cache into the same object.

```js
let data = [
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Mustang', model: 'EcoBoost' },
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Mustang', model: 'GTFastback' },
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Mustang', model: 'DarkHorse' },
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Escape', model: 'Active' },
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Escape', model: 'Platium' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Camry', model: 'XSE' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Camry', model: 'TRD' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Camry', model: 'XLE' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Supra', model: '2.0' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Supra', model: '3.0' }
]

//groups, starting with a root.
const g = { _: [] };
const add = (arr, item) => (arr.push(item), item);

for (const { manufacture, make, model } of data) {
  const a = g[manufacture] ??= add(g._, { manufacture, makes: [] });
  const b = g[manufacture + ":" + make] ??= add(a.makes, { make, models: [] });
  b.models.push({ model });
}

//console.log(g);
console.log(g._);
```

this code is basically a bunch of `get` or `create` operations. And when creating add the created element to the parent group.

A more verbose version of the loop would be

```js
for (const { manufacture, make, model } of data) {
  if (!g[manufacture]) {
    g[manufacture] = { manufacture, makes: [] };
    g._.push(g[manufacture]);
  }

  if (!g[manufacture + ":" + make]) {
    g[manufacture + ":" + make] = { make, models: [] };
    g[manufacture].makes.push(g[manufacture + ":" + make]);
  }

  g[manufacture + ":" + make].push({ model })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataset can be a valid array of objects, you can do something like below.  Not a 'simple' way by any means, and there might be a simpler way, but this is one way to get you the format you need.

```js
let data = [
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Mustang', model: 'EcoBoost' },
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Mustang', model: 'GTFastback' },
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Mustang', model: 'DarkHorse' },
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Escape', model: 'Active' },
  { manufacture: 'Ford', make: 'Escape', model: 'Platium' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Camry', model: 'XSE' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Camry', model: 'TRD' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Camry', model: 'XLE' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Supra', model: '2.0' },
  { manufacture: 'Toyota', make: 'Supra', model: '3.0' }
]

let manufacturers = [...new Set(data.map((m) => m.manufacture))]
let makes = (manufacture) => [...new Set(data.filter((a) => a.manufacture === manufacture).map((m) => m.make))]
let models = (make) => [...new Set(data.filter((a) => a.make === make).map((m) => m.model))]

let result = manufacturers.map((i) => ({
  manufacture: i,
  makes: makes(i).map((j) => ({
    make: j,
    models: models(j).map((k) => ({
      model: k
    }))
  }))
}))

console.log(result)
```